# Turn a straight line plot into a curved one using seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if anyone knows how to curve an originally straight line using matplotlib or seaborn? The reason is that I have many lines going from points A to B.

I have attached a specific example here. I have three lines going from points A to B. Without curving two of them, I won't be able to tell there are three lines (first figure). Only by curving two lines can you tell that there are actually three lines going from A to B (second figure; I added the curve manually).

[image: originally straight line plot]
[image: curved line plots]

Comment: What is the point of a plot if it doesn't represent the data faithfully? You might be looking for a diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I see no purpose in "curving" the line and actually making a false data. But here you go:

```py
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(50)
y = np.arange(50)
ax.plot(x, y)

a_red = patches.FancyArrowPatch((x[0], y[0]), (x[-1], y[-1]), connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0.1", arrowstyle="Simple, tail_width=0.5, head_width=4, head_length=8", color='r')
a_gre = patches.FancyArrowPatch((x[0], y[0]), (x[-1], y[-1]), connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.1", arrowstyle="Simple, tail_width=0.5, head_width=4, head_length=8", color='g')
plt.gca().add_patch(a_red)
plt.gca().add_patch(a_gre)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Curving" a line is a bit vague. The best way would probably be to change the equation of the line you're plotting, but to keep points A and B at the ends.

However, a better solution might be to simply change the opacity of the lines that you are plotting so that you can see when they overlap. Use matplotlib's alpha parameter to do this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]

plt.plot(x, y, "blue", linewidth=5, alpha=0.3)
```